# populate UI from local db table initially, then if webserivice has new data update table and UI

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-loadermanager

ok this is my first post,

i have a ListView that is populated from local db table. from there i have to check if there is new data available from web service, if so first i have to update that particular table then UI.

now i need rough idea on how to implement this?

the data from web service isn't going to change frequently. so i need to create some architecture/mechanism where data is always loaded from database first then if new data is available from web service then i parse service update table then update UI.

basically i want something like this

```
    MainThread
        |
        |
        |-------->>--------separate thread----->>-----|
        |                                             |
        |                    listener/              query db,
   populate UI <<----------- observer/  ------<<----get data 
        |                    something                |
        |                                             |
        |                                             |
        |                                             |
        |                               check if we have new data--->> if no-- DONE       
        |                                             |
        |                                           if yes
        |                                             |
        |                                     call web service,
        |                                         fetch data,
        |                                        update table
        |                     listener/               |
    update UI  <<-------------observer/-----<<--------|
        |                     something               
        |
```

Kinda like Tumblr android App..

now i think i can achieve this with wrapping AsyncTask inside a class and an Interface(as observer/listener)

but i like to use Loader(available in android),

any other suggestion ?

Comment: So use AsyncTaskLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question !

It seems that you are trying to achieve the Famous Google I/O design pattern? 
[Google IO Rest design pattern, Finished ContentProvider and stuck now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112658/google-io-rest-design-pattern-finished-contentprovider-and-stuck-now)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

I did it in the past (maybe as not as well as it should have been done ;-) ). And my advice is be sure of this two points :

- Your tables are not too complex
- Your updates are not always occuring.

If it's not the case, you 'll probably face performance issues due to database accesses.
But it's a really good pattern.

Another advice is to use an Event bus instead  of boiler-plate, frustrating interfaces for updating the UI . (I usaully use this one https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus no performance problems, Otto is good and simple too but does not integrate well with android-annotations).

Hope it'll help.

Comment: well thanks for pointing out the REST architecture. i used "REST Methods, Using a Service API". tweaked it a bit according to my requirement. i implemented it with Loader.

and thanks for mentioning EventBus.

Comment: So later i found this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module. whoever wants to implement something like "image in asked question" or manipulate their response before presenting in UI this is highly useful. plus use cases of RxJava is not limited to only this. its very versatile. please check it out.